SQL code which performs a similar function as Excel VLookup
I was wondering if someone could please help me with the following SQL code.
I have a table which has a list of employees with all their details. I have a sample table with the columns below



forename
surname
posn_ref
line_mamanger
line_mamanger_posn_ref




aaa
bbb
123
ccc ddd



ccc
ddd
456
eee cvb



xxx
yyy
789
zzz hhh



zzz
hhh
890
ggg sas



ggg
sas
322
hnj mnb



eee
cvb
334
klj vvc




my table is called employees.
What I am trying to achieve is to look at the line_manger of an employee (columns 1 & 2) and return the posn_ref number of the line manager and add it in the last column (line_mamanger_posn_ref). so in the example above the line manager for employees aaa, is 'ccc ddd' and the posn_ref of ccc ddd is 456 so in line_mamanger_posn_ref for employees aaa it will insert 456 and so on.
I hope this is clear, I only have one table but I need to add the line_mamanger_posn_ref values for each employee which corresponds to the ref number of the manager. I am using Google Bigquer SQL (standard SQL)
Any help is appreciated

Odd set of tags.  is for MS SQL Server and  for Postgresql.

Reconsider this table design to avoid storing repetitive data that take up resources. Ideally you maintain a single employees table with full names and a relational table of employee_managers storing two columns of integer values.

Why does it appear that you have two variable for the employee name and only one variable for the manager name?  Are you sure the names form a unique key for this dataset? There might be multiple John Smith's in a company that are each managers, how will you tell them apart?

Just a join back on its self is enough (this is for tsql not psql, although the implementation should be similar):
UPDATE e
SET line_manager_posn_ref = manager.posn_ref
FROM employee AS e
JOIN employee AS manager
    ON e.line_manager = manager.forename + ' ' + manager.surname


Note that OP seems to be using Google Bigquery.

Thanks for this, I am using big query sql and can't get this working also one thing to mention is line_mamanger_posn_ref doesnt exists I do need to add the column and enter the relevant values in

Arh right. Well sorry I have zero experience with google bigquery.  Although I have used azure's version which uses much the same of sql but is very simplistic in features available. It might be better to add a calculated field to join the person's names together. Also on the column not existing, you could just use an alter statement (again no bigquery experience, just assuming you can)
